# jQuery("#myCarousel").jcarousel is not a function?

Tags: jquery, function, jcarousel

I am new to jQuery. I am trying to use the example "simple" jCarousel in my asp.net pages.
I have a top.master page that contains the head content which contains the javascript to setup myCarousel.

There are no spelling errors in myCarousel which is used in the setup section. Now when I use FireFox with firebug, as soon the script for setting up jCarousel is hit, it throws an error, `jQuery("#myCarousel").jcarousel` is not a function'

What am I doing wrong here?
EDIT
OK below is what goes to top.master

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#myCarousel').jcarousel({
        // Configuration goes here
    });
});
</script> and in results.aspx i have the following <p> <ul id="myCarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-tango"><% foreach..... %></ul></p>
```

Comment: You need to make sure that 1. your loading jcarousel in your source and 2. your using `(document).ready(function(){/*....*/})`

Comment: Could we perhaps see some code? It's really hard to geuss without a code sample

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure you are loading jQuery and jCarousel files correctly. =)

Comment: Thats loaded OK for other things I do.

Comment: I cant believe I had undone the loading of jquery.jcarousel.min.js!!!!! THANKS ANYWAY

Answer (score 1):

Functions should be written like this: `jQuery("#myCarousel").jcarousel()`

Make sure you have included the jcarousel script.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#myCarousel').jcarousel();
});
```

Also, make sure that your id is myCarousel and not mycarousel as they are case sensitive.